# Internal SSD not found when installing macOS

Tags: macos, mac, hardware, upgrade, ssd

I just upgraded my Mac Mini Late 2012 to an SSD. Now, I wanted to boot from my bootable USB and then install macOS to my SSD but it does not find the SSD when I want to select it. The SSD is from [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JN1TY9U).

This is the screen I'm stuck on:

[image: macOS does not find my SSD]

Also, I rebooted the Mac and held the `alt` key pressed but there was only the *OS X Base System* (which appears to be the USB Stick, since when I removed it and rebooted it did not find anything) selectable option.

So I opened the DiskUtility program and I see the SSD. Is there a way to use it?

And yes, I am sure that I connected everything properly.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure the SSD is in the correct format. Go to Disk Utility, and in the Erase tab, select Mac OS Extended (Journaled) as the format and erase the SSD, and then the bootable drive should acknowledge the SSD as a disk on which OS X can be installed. Good luck!